# Vue filter in component

Tags: filter, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

```
[Vue warn]: Property or method "onlyNumbers" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.

<template>
<div class="category-info">
    <div v-for="input in inputs.text">
        <label >{{ input.placeholder}}</label>
        <input type="text"  id="location" :name="input.name" v-model="input.value | onlyNumbers" @change="inputChange">
    </div>
    <div class="select" v-for="select in inputs.select">
        <label >{{ select.placeholder }}</label>
        <my-select :data="select" v-model="select.value" @change="selectChange(select)"></my-select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hi all i want to filter value from input text, i created filter in 2 ways  but all time have this error, how to do that?

1 try

```
Vue.filter('onlyNumbers',function (value) {

    return +value.replace(/[^\d.]/g, '');

});
```

2 try

```
 export default {
    name: "profile-add-inputs",
    props: ['category'],
    data() {
        return {
            inputs: {
                text : {},
                select: {}
            },
        }
    },
    methods: {
        getCategories(){
         /////
       },
        selectChange(select){
            ///
        },
        inputChange(){
            /// some code what i have
        }
    },
    filters : {
        onlyNumbers: function (value) {

            return +value.replace(/[^\d.]/g, '');

        }
    },
    watch: {
        category : function () {
            this.getCategories();
        },
    }
}
```

But always i had had this error

my eror is add.js:32380 [Vue warn]: Property or method "onlyNumbers" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property

Answer (score 0):

> Refer to [this](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#Filters-Outside-Text-Interpolations-removed) to get more information why your filter does not work.
>
> And then refer to [this](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#Two-Way-Filters-replaced) to learn how to use two-way-filters

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to validate the input on the onchange event

I modified your code a bit for a working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/4rr9nv1p70

You find it in the file `App.vue`